# How to count the total number of reports for each month using stored timestamp data and output in a json array format

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am creating a surveillance website where the users make reports. These reports are being stored in a table called `sent_report` with each report having its own timestamp value.

Now I want to get the total number of reports made for each month (i.e for Jan, Feb,...Dec) based on those timestamp values and store it in an array like format which can be used to plot a graph using a JavaScript library

I have tried many SQL queries all to no avail, that I can't even remember them all

I would like my output to look something like this

```
Jan: 0,Feb: 0,Marc: 3,Apr: 7,...,Dec: 10
```

My Table looks something like this

```
Id | Surname | Firstname |   Content   |    Report_date
 1 |  David  |  Johnson  | Lorem Ipsum | 2019-02-24 01:14:18
 2 |  Jason  |   Jimmy   | Lorem Ipsum | 2019-08-24 15:44:20
 3 |   Sam   |  Robinson | Lorem Ipsum | 2019-08-24 13:54:44
 4 |  Karla  |  Thompson | Lorem Ipsum | 2019-05-24 09:14:12
```

Note that am not trying to get the contents of each row, but the count as regards to the timestamp

or if possible in an array format that can be used to plot a graph in JavaScript. How can I do that?

**Updated**
My PHP Code

```
require '../../users/docs/connection.php';

$query = sprintf("SELECT 
    SUM(IF(MONTH(report_time) = 1 , 1 , 0)) AS Jan,
    SUM(IF(MONTH(report_time) = 2 , 1 , 0)) AS Feb,
    SUM(IF(MONTH(report_time) = 3 , 1 , 0)) AS Mar,
    SUM(IF(MONTH(report_time) = 4 , 1 , 0)) AS Apr,
    SUM(IF(MONTH(report_time) = 5 , 1 , 0)) AS May,
    SUM(IF(MONTH(report_time) = 6 , 1 , 0)) AS Jun,
    SUM(IF(MONTH(report_time) = 7 , 1 , 0)) AS Jul,
    SUM(IF(MONTH(report_time) = 8 , 1 , 0)) AS Aug,
    SUM(IF(MONTH(report_time) = 9 , 1 , 0)) AS Sep,
    SUM(IF(MONTH(report_time) = 10 , 1 , 0)) AS 'Oct',
    SUM(IF(MONTH(report_time) = 11 , 1 , 0)) AS Nov,
    SUM(IF(MONTH(report_time) = 12 , 1 , 0)) AS 'Dec'
FROM sent_reports
WHERE YEAR(report_time) = 2019");

$result = $conn->query($query);
$data = array();

foreach ($result as $row) {
    $data[] = $row;
}

$result->close();
$conn->close();

print json_encode($data);
```

**Updated** My JavaScript Code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/projects/DiseaseSurvey/admin/docs/charts-data.php",
        method: "GET",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
    })
})
```

Comment: Please update your question with your table structure and show the queries you have tried.

Comment: Try `GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(sent_datetime, '%Y-%m')` and use `COUNT(0)` in select statment

Comment: @Jitendra Yadav this didn't work sir

Comment: @Nick this is my first question on stackoverflow....so i don't really know how to use it that well...hw do i make a dummy of my table structure here?

Comment: @RedemptionOkoro [edit] your question and cut and paste the result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE sent_report` into it

Comment: @Nick i have updated my question with a quick view of how my data looks like

Comment: @RedemptionOkoro, add you PHP code in which you are fetching data from database and accessing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1: **One row per Month**(only include months which have any report sent):

If you want one-row per month then make sure you have selected one year only otherwise for `Jan` month you will count from all years.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(Report_date,'%b') AS Month_Name, COUNT(0) AS Report_Count
FROM sent_report
WHERE YEAR(Report_date) = 2019         -- It is important otherwise you can have multiple Jan month from year 2018, 2019...
GROUP BY MONTH(sent_datetime);


Output:
+---------------------------+
| Month_Name | Report_Count |
| Jan        | 10           |
| Feb        | 5            |
| ..         | ..           |
+---------------------------+
```

2: **One row per Month - including all months**

To fetch all months even though there are no reports sent against them. Create a temp table which has all months name and then do left join with the above query.

```
SELECT 
    months.Month_Name,
    IFNULL(reports.Report_Count, 0) Report_Count
FROM (
   SELECT 'Jan' AS Month_Name 
   UNION SELECT 'Feb'
   UNION SELECT 'Mar'
   UNION SELECT 'Apr'
   UNION SELECT 'May'
   UNION SELECT 'Jun'
   UNION SELECT 'Jul'
   UNION SELECT 'Aug'
   UNION SELECT 'Sep'
   UNION SELECT 'Oct'
   UNION SELECT 'Nov'
   UNION SELECT 'Dec'
) AS months
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        DATE_FORMAT(Report_date,'%b') AS Month_Name, 
        COUNT(0) AS Report_Count
    FROM sent_report
    WHERE YEAR(Report_date) = 2019         -- It is important otherwise you can have multiple Jan month from year 2018, 2019...
    GROUP BY MONTH(Report_date)
) AS reports ON months.Month_Name = reports.Month_Name;
```

3: **One row includes all months as columns**.

```
SELECT 
    SUM(IF(MONTH(Report_date) = 1 , 1 , 0)) AS Jan,
    SUM(IF(MONTH(Report_date) = 2 , 1 , 0)) AS Feb,
    SUM(IF(MONTH(Report_date) = 3 , 1 , 0)) AS Mar,
    SUM(IF(MONTH(Report_date) = 4 , 1 , 0)) AS Apr,
    SUM(IF(MONTH(Report_date) = 5 , 1 , 0)) AS May,
    SUM(IF(MONTH(Report_date) = 6 , 1 , 0)) AS Jun,
    SUM(IF(MONTH(Report_date) = 7 , 1 , 0)) AS Jul,
    SUM(IF(MONTH(Report_date) = 8 , 1 , 0)) AS Aug,
    SUM(IF(MONTH(Report_date) = 9 , 1 , 0)) AS Sep,
    SUM(IF(MONTH(Report_date) = 10 , 1 , 0)) AS 'Oct',
    SUM(IF(MONTH(Report_date) = 11 , 1 , 0)) AS Nov,
    SUM(IF(MONTH(Report_date) = 12 , 1 , 0)) AS 'Dec'
FROM sent_report
WHERE YEAR(Report_date) = 2019         -- It is important otherwise you can have multiple Jan month from year 2018, 2019...

Output:

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | May | Jun | Jul | Aug | Sep | Oct | Nov | Dec |
| 2   | 5   | 7   | 1   | 0   | 1   | 8   | 1   |  4  | 2   | 1   | 2   |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: it worked but, i also want it to print out zero values for the months with no reports...Thank you in advance 

Comment: @RedemptionOkoro, see my updated answer, which addresses your this issue too.

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience but i would like it to be outputed like the previous one, but this time with the zero values for the months without a report....although it looks good so far and am grateful, but any idea on how i could convert this to a javascript readable array format

Comment: @RedemptionOkoro I have added another section in between which outputs like the previous one too. :)

Comment: @RedemptionOkoro, if it works for you, do accept the answer, by clicking on right tick icon below vote up and down in anser. [Accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: It worked Sir, but i still need to send this data to javascript as an array for it to be used to plot a graph. i would appriciate any help i can get.

Comment: @RedemptionOkoro, Can you show me how it is being displayed in your javascript and how you want it?

Comment: i haven't even been able to store it a variable not to even talk about taking it to javascript. I want it to be stored as an array and sent to javascript, either by using json format and ajax or some other way

Comment: @RedemptionOkoro, show PHP code and I think for you it would be better to use 3rd query, as it will return one row and using PDO in PHP, you can just make a JSON object and send it to PHP.

Comment: Sir i have updated my question - added my php code, have a look at it above

Comment: @RedemptionOkoro, just pick the first row. `echo json_encode($result[0]);` and send the output in chat.

Comment: it returns all the data in one object of an array and not a separate object for each data set in an array...by the way i have also inserted my javascript code in the question above..

Comment: @RedemptionOkoro, Let me clarify, if you want this `[{"Jan":1}, {"Feb",2}..]` in javascript then use the `second mysql query` and in PHP for each loop do this `$data[] = [$row['Month_Name'] => $row['Report_Count']]`;

Comment: Yes sir....that is exactly what i want to archive, but when using the second query it gives me and sql syntax error for the left join part, maybe you should explain that second query to me some more....i understand the first and third, but not the second. Thank You

Comment: Updated the second query. You have to remove comma before left join. Will explain later, right now in office.

Comment: Okay sir....am looking forward to your explanations, i will try the updated query to now